# ORACLE - Return cursor from stored procedure

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures

I need to return a cursor object from a stored procedure, but I need to process data first.

For example, let's consider this simple stored procedure:

```
create or replace PROCEDURE TEST 
(
   query_str IN VARCHAR2,
   CURSOR_ OUT SYS_REFCURSOR
)
AS
BEGIN
   OPEN CURSOR_ FOR query_str;
END;
```

This procedure returns data as is, with no postprocessing.
The improvement I need is the following:

1. process data coming from the execution of query_str;
2. return the processed data in the form of a cursor.

Anyone could suggest me a way to accomplish this?

Thanks

Comment: What kind of processing do you need to do, and why can't it be done as part of the query used to define the ref cursor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is difficult to do what you are suggesting with dynamic SQL (unless all the statements you are passing to the procedure all have a similar output format). If you can know what the `SELECT` will be then you can store it in a collection and process it:

```
CREATE TABLE TEST_DATA ( id, name, dt ) AS
  SELECT 1, 'A', SYSDATE FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 'B', DATE '2017-01-01' FROM DUAL;

CREATE TYPE processed_data_obj AS OBJECT(
  id   INTEGER,
  etag VARCHAR2(20)
);
/

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE processed_data_table AS TABLE OF processed_data_obj;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE TEST 
(
   CURSOR_ OUT SYS_REFCURSOR
)
AS
  processed PROCESSED_DATA_TABLE;
BEGIN
  -- Process it in the select statement
  SELECT processed_data_obj(
           id,
           name || '_' || ROUND( ( dt - DATE '1970-01-01' ) * 24*60*60 )
         )
  BULK COLLECT INTO processed
  FROM  test_data;

  -- Process it more in PL/SQL
  FOR i IN 1 .. processed.COUNT LOOP
    processed[i].etag := processed[i].etag || '_' || i;
  END LOOP;

  OPEN cursor_out FOR
    SELECT *
    FROM   TABLE( processed );
END;
/
```

Comment: Just a question. I'm using SqlDeveloper to write my stored procedure. No problem if I write it in a SQL worksheet (the sheet in which you can write a query too). But, after I executed the procedure, If I open it, I find only the code starting from "CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE TEST ...". Where can i write all the statements (CREATE TYPE, ... )? So that, when I call the stored from a Java app, all the statements could be run

Comment: @Fab The `CREATE TYPE` statements are stored in Oracle's data dictionary - you can find them in SQL Developer using the same method you use for procedures; just expand the `Types` sub-folder under the connections tab rather than the `Procedures` folder and they will be listed there. However, when you have created the types once they will exist forever - you do not need to recreate them each time the procedure is called.

Comment: I found both procedure and types created. But the question is another. I'm going to call the procedure using Java by `call TEST(?)` and I think only the `CREATE PROCEDURE` code will be executed. So, the possibilities are 2: my types are already available or.... is there a way to run all the `CREATE` statements when I call the procedure?

Comment: @Fab If you have run the `CREATE TYPE` statements once then the types will already be created and you do **not** need to run those statements again every time you call the procedure.

Comment: Yes, I know that. I'm asking just out of curiosity, to know if there is a way to combine the CREATE statements in a single call. Anyway, your solution is what I was looking for

Comment: @Fab no - they are separate DDL statements.